# Sequelize filter nested includes

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 3 tables

```
Post: post_id, name

TermRelationship: post_id, term_taxonomy_id

TermTaxonomy: term_taxonomy_id, name
```

Relationships:

`Post` to `TermRelationship` is One to Many

`TermRelationship` to `TermTaxonomy` is One to One

I am finding a post with all of its data like this and everything is fine:

```
  Post.findOne({
    where: { post_id: 351043 },
    include: [
      {
        model: TermRelationships,
        include: [{ model: TermTaxonomy }]
      }
    ]
  })
```

**Now the thing is that I don't want ALL `TermRelationships` I want just the ones that have `name` set to `RandomName`**

I tried many ways that I found on the internet but nothing made it work, the last try I made was like this

```
  Post.findOne({
    where: { post_id: 351043 },
    include: [
      PostMeta,
      {
        model: TermRelationships,
        include: [{ model: TermTaxonomy, where: { name: "RandomName" } }]
      }
    ]
  })
```

but this returns `null` instead of the post with an empty `TermRelationship` array.

My best guess was that I should put the where clause in the upper level and do something like this:

```
  Post.findOne({
    where: { post_id: 351043 },
    include: [
      PostMeta,
      {
        model: TermRelationships,
        include: [{ model: TermTaxonomy }],
        where: { "$TermTaxonomy.name$": "RandomName" }
      }
    ]
  })
```

but it returns `Unknown column 'TermTaxonomy.name' in 'where clause'`

The TermTaxonomy has a column named `name` and the error just does not make sense to me.

Am I missing a big point here or this should work and I probably have the set up wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I read the documentation again and realized that my second table `TermRelationship` was there only for mapping and there is actually really cool way to implement the `N:M` relationships explained in detail here in the [Belongs-To-Many associations chapter](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/associations.html).

Pretty much I designed the models using the `belongsToMany` function like:

```
// this will map Post's primary key to the "post_id" column of the TermRelationships table

Post.belongsToMany(TermTaxonomy, {
  foreignKey: "post_id",
  through: "TermRelationships"
});

// this will map TermTaxonomy primary key to the "term_taxonomy_id" column of the 

TermRelationships table
    TermTaxonomy.belongsToMany(Post, {
      foreignKey: "term_taxonomy_id",
      through: "TermRelationships"
    });
```

It is important to do the 2 way binding since if you don't Sequelize will try to "guess" the column names and keys and sometimes this would lead to unexpected errors.

Then a simple did the trick (please pay attention to the `required: false` in the `include`

```
  Post.findOne({
    where: { ID: 351043 },
    include: [{ model: TermTaxonomy, where: { name: "RandomName" }, required: false }]
  })
```

**Note the first approach was actually not THAT bad but I needed something like this:**

```
  Post.findOne({
    where: { post_id: 351043 },
    include: [
      PostMeta,
      {
        model: TermRelationships,
        include: [{ model: TermTaxonomy, where: { name: "RandomName" }, required: false }]
      }
    ]
  })
```

That is pretty much my first possible example where it returns `null` instead of the post with empty array of TermTaxonomy.

The key here is to add `required: false` to the `include`, that way it will return an array of elements, some of them `null` and then you can say that you need the ones that are not `null` (much harder than the other solution I found)

Answer (score 0):

The Eager loading section of the [sequelize manual](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-usage.html) seems to indicate you would do it like so:

```
  Post.findOne({
    where: { post_id: 351043 },
    include: [
      {
        model: TermRelationships,
        where: { name: "RandomName" }
      }
    ]
  })
```